# Hessian of quadratic form of function using Hadamard and Frobenius notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, jacobian, hessian-matrix, hadamard-product

Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3141990/mathbbc-mathbbr-calculus-for-quadratic-form) question, I am trying to compute the Hessian of
$$
g(r, \theta) = [r\cos(\theta)]^{\top} A \, [r\cos(\theta)] = f(r, \theta) ^{\top} A \, f(r, \theta) \tag{$*$}
$$
for $r, \theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A = A^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $f(r, \theta) = r \cos(\theta)$ is computed component-wise. Ideally, I hope to obtain a form for the Hessian of ($*$) using Hadamard and Frobenius notation (I have had trouble computing the Hessian from the formula given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562937/hessian-of-non-linear-quadratic-form).

Here is my attempt at computing gradients, where $C_{\theta} := \text{diag}(\cos(\theta))$, $S_{\theta} := \text{diag}(\sin(\theta))$, and $R := \text{diag}(R)$.
\begin{align}
\nabla_{\theta}g &= \nabla_{\theta} \{ (\cos(\theta)^{\top}(R  A  R) \cos(\theta) \} \\
&= -S_{\theta} (R  A  R) \cos(\theta) \tag{1}
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
\nabla_{r}g &= \nabla_{r} \{ r^{\top}(C_{\theta} A C_{\theta}) r \} \\ 
&= (C_{\theta} A C_{\theta}) r \tag{2}
\end{align}
Now, I'm having trouble computing the second order terms from (1) and (2). Specifically, I'm having trouble computing the Jacobians:
$$
D_{\theta} \{ -S_{\theta} (R  A  R) \cos(\theta) \}
$$
and
$$
D_{\theta} \{ (C_{\theta} A C_{\theta}) r \}.
$$
Is there a clean way of doing this? As an alternative, I tried applying the formula 
$$
D^2g_x = Df_x^{\top} (A + A^{\top}) Df_x + D^2f_x (A + A^{\top}) f(x)
$$
(for $x := (x^{r}, x^{\theta})^{\top}$) but had difficulty working with the final $D^2f_x (A + A^{\top}) f(x)$ term.

Comment: what are the dimensions of $r$ and $\theta$? How is $r \cos(\theta)$ computed for vectors?

Comment: @LinAlg: Thanks, I have $r, \theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define some variables
$$\eqalign{
c &= \cos(\theta), \quad C = {\rm Diag}(c) \cr
s &= \sin(\theta), \quad S = {\rm Diag}(s), \quad R = {\rm Diag}(r) \cr
f &= c\odot r \cr
df &= c\odot dr - s\odot r\odot d\theta \cr
 b &= Af \cr
db &= A\,df = AC\,dr - ARS\,d\theta \cr
}$$
Write the g-function in terms of these new variables and find its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 g &= A:ff^T \cr
dg &= A:(f\,df^T+df\,f^T) \cr
 &= (A+A^T):df\,f^T \cr
 &= 2b:df \cr
 &= 2b:c\odot dr - 2b:s\odot r\odot d\theta \cr
 &= 2c\odot b:dr - 2s\odot r\odot b:d\theta \cr
}$$
So the two gradients are
$$\eqalign{
g_r &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} = 2c\odot b \cr
g_\theta &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta} = -2s\odot r\odot b \cr
}$$
Now find the differential and gradients of $g_r$
$$\eqalign{
dg_r
 &= 2C\,db + 2B\,dc \cr
 &= 2C(AC\,dr - ARS\,d\theta) - 2B(S\,d\theta) \cr
 &= 2CAC\,dr - 2(CARS+BS)\,d\theta \cr
g_{rr} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} &= 2CAC \cr
g_{r\theta} = \frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta} &= -2(CAR+B)S \cr
}$$
Similarly, $g_{\theta\theta}$ and $g_{\theta r}$ can be calculated as the gradients of $g_\theta$